# Tkinter Installation Issue

Tags: python3, tkinter

```
user@Embedded-10:~/python_programs$ pip install Tkinter
Collecting Tkinter
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/tkinter/
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome! it seems this address is not valid https://pypi.org/simple/tkinter/, you can try [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `pip` for installing `Tkinter` (version 2.x) or `pip3` for installing  `tkinter` (version 3.x). They are available natively in Ubuntu and you can have both versions installed at the same time. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter):

> **Tkinter** is a Python binding to the Tk GUI toolkit. It is the standard Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit,[2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) and is Python's de
>   facto standard GUI.[3](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/) Tkinter is included with standard Linux,
>   Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X installs of Python.

For myself I did have to install Pillow (fork of PIL) for image processing. In this case you still don't need `pip` or `pip3` but rather `sudo apt install` is used. For example here is what I installed recently:

```
$ grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log | grep -i pil
2019-12-02 20:31:46 install python-pil:amd64 <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
2019-12-04 16:43:04 install python-pil.imagetk:amd64 <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
2019-12-04 16:43:11 install python3-pil.imagetk:amd64 <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
2019-12-04 18:59:08 install python-pil-doc:all <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
2019-12-04 18:59:10 install python-pil-dbg:amd64 <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
2019-12-04 18:59:10 install python-pil.imagetk-dbg:amd64 <none> 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1
```

With Pillow imaging you can display images like screenshots in a Tkinter canvas:

[image: wman.png]

Comment: I think it's the right comment to the wrong person

Comment: you are right! read it wrong...